# radioButtons() input as a condition to filter a data frame in Shiny, doesn't seem to work

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

Using the `midwest` dataframe from `ggplot2`:

```r
# (in app_ui.r)

poverty_sidebar <- sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "state",
    label = "State",
    choices = list("IL" = 1, "IN" = 2, "MI" = 3, "OH" = 4, "WI" = 5),
    selected = 1
  ))

poverty_plot <- mainPanel(
  plotOutput(
    outputId = "poverty_plot"
  )
)

# (in app_server.r)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$poverty_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    filtered <- filter(midwest, state == input$state)
    
    plot <- ggplot(data = filtered) +
      geom_col(x = county, y = poppovertyknown)
    
    return(plot)
  })
```

Doesn't seem to work, gives me a "Object `county` not found" error. is doing `filter(midwest, state == input$state)` the wrong approach? Or does the error lie with my radio buttons?

Comment: Try with `choices = list("IL" , "IN" , "MI" , "OH" , "WI" )`

Comment: Gives me the same error: "Object `county` not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the code provided is close, you are making two mistakes

1. `choices` does not need to map to numeric
2. `x = county, y = poppovertyknown` should be in the `aes` of `geom_col` so `aes(x = county, y = poppovertyknown)`

Hence the final working code would be (Note I have added assignment to `ui` to make it work in single file with call to `shinyApp(ui, server)`),

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


poverty_sidebar <- sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "state",
    label = "State",
    choices = list("IL", "IN", "MI", "OH", "WI"), # remove mapping to integers
    selected = "IL"
  ))

poverty_plot <- mainPanel(
  plotOutput(
    outputId = "poverty_plot"
  )
)

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    poverty_sidebar,
    poverty_plot
  )
  

# (in app_server.r)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$poverty_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    filtered <- filter(midwest, state == input$state)
    print(filtered)
    print(input$state)
    filtered0 <<- filtered
    plot <- 
      filtered %>% 
      ggplot() +
      geom_col(aes(x = county, y = poppovertyknown)) # used aes()
    
    return(plot)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The little mistakes that ruin everything. Thanks so much!